# Return to a fragment already created

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm working on an Android application that uses fragments.
The code is supposed to do the following:

1. I'm in the mainActivity;
2. In here there's a button that creates a fragment;
3. Turn on an on/off button;
4. I go back to the mainActivity;
5. I click on the button and go to the created fragment;
6. The on/off button is turned on;

I tried to implement this and it doesn't work. In step 5 I believe that it's creating a new fragment everytime, because the on/off button is always turned off.

Basically want I want is to go back to the same fragment that I created firstly.

This is the current code that I have:

MainActivity:

```
public void onStartSensors(View view) {
    if(count > 0){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else{
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, new StartupFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        count++;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
In the link bellow, I got a representation of the present state of my application. When I enter the fragment for the second time, I want it to keep the accelerometer ON.
https://ibb.co/Sc7QZDt
I already tried the method popBackStack(), added a tag, name etc. and it doesn't work.
When I get out of the fragment the method getFragmentByTag() returns null.

This is the current state of the code:

```
public void onStartSensors(View view) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(count > 0){
        StartupFragment f1= (StartupFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("A");
        FragmentTransaction transaction=fm.beginTransaction();
        if( f1 != null) {
            transaction.attach(f1);
            transaction.addToBackStack("sensors");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
    else{
        StartupFragment f1=new StartupFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, f1, "A");
        transaction.addToBackStack("sensors");
        transaction.commit();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I go back to the mainActivity;` from where ? perhaps i'm missing something but from what you've explained you should still be on the same activity ?

Comment: As I understand it, you're adding a fragment to be displayed on top of an Activity, and you want some way for that to be hidden and shown?

Comment: First of all you are creating a new fragment on every function call, second if you want to make the back stack work then why you pass null to addToBackStack function

Comment: @AsadMukhtar I already tried with null and with a tag and both ways don't work

Comment: @a_local_nobody When I say "I go back to the mainActivity" it means that I get out of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to add a fragment to be displayed on top of the current activity that is able to be hidden and shown on demand. Looking at your code, every time you are 'showing' the fragment you are creating a new `StartupFragment` so the behaviour you are experiencing makes sense.

So I would instead recommend adding the fragment when the activity starts and then using [`FragmentTransaction.show(Fragment)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#show(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) and [`FragmentTransaction.hide(Fragment)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#hide(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) to toggle it's visibility.